# Regex Expresion

Tags: formula-field, validation-rule, regular-expressions

Hi can someone help me to put this regex in a validation rule

NOT(REGEX( Video_Title__c, "[?\b(?:word)\b]?"))

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When using escape sequences like `\b` in regex in Salesforce, you need to add an extra backslash

so `"\\]?\\b(?:word)\\b\\]?"` in that REGEX() function would be syntactically correct, though perhaps not semantically correct.
Perhaps you meant for that `(?:word)` to be `(?:\\w)`?

If you want to match a literal backslash, you need 4 backslashes `\\\\`